# Number invariant problem: replacing any two numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a - 1$ and $b + 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., 2014 are written on a blackboard. Every now and then somebody picks two numbers $a$ and $b$ and replaces them by $a - 1$, $b + 3$. Is it possible that at some point all numbers on the blackboard are even? Can they all be odd?

I cannot figure out how to use the terms $a - 1$ and $b  + 3$ to form a invariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, since with every replacing, the number of odd numbers either stays the same, increases by 2 or decreases by 2. Since at the start there is an odd number of odd numbers, it will always stay odd, especially it will never be 2014. The same argument applies for the number of even numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: subtracting $1$ or adding $3$ changes a number's parity (i.e. it goes from odd to even or vice versa).  When you do this to two numbers, the number of odd numbers on the blackboard  changes by either $-2$, $0$ or $+2$.

Comment: Since he asked for an invariant: the invariant then is the sum $\pmod{2}$.

Comment: So it is not possible for all the numbers on the blackboard to be even or all odd, correct?

Comment: Neither $0$ nor $2014$ being odd, that is correct.

Comment: What I'm asking is the answer to the following questions: "Is it possible that at some point all numbers on the blackboard are even? Can they all be odd?" I am saying no for both.

Comment: What don't you understand about the answers you have been given?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, at some point all the numbers on the board can be odd (or even).  The possibilities for each step are the following:

1. Erase two even numbers, then write two odd numbers.
2. Erase two odd numbers, then write two even numbers.
3. Erase an even number and an odd number, then write an odd number and an even number.

Initially there are $1007$ even numbers and $1007$ odd numbers on the board.  Repeat step (1) until all the numbers but one are odd (or even).  Then carry out step (3).  Just after you erase $a$ and $b$, and before you write $a-1$ and $b+3$, all the numbers on the board are odd (or even).

Comment: Step three produces one odd and one even, so after step 3 all numbers cannot have same parity...

Comment: Correct, *after* step 3 all numbers don't have the same parity.  Read what I wrote again.

Comment: While technically you are correct, I doubt that this is what the problem is about. And if you want to be nick-picking, replaces doesn't necessarily mean "erase and then write"... If I want to replace 1999 by 1998, I would definitely not erase 1999, I would only erase the last digit .....

Comment: I suspect there's a way to make it come it right in that case as well.